# Loop through text file stripping part of the string using batch

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe

How can I use windows command line to do the following?

```
C:\Users\My Computer\SkyDrive\WORK ORDERS\Subdivision\Sec. 1\12345678_123 LUMINAIRE LN.pdf

becomes

WORK ORDERS\Subdivision\Sec. 1\12345678_123 LUMINAIRE LN.pdf
```

I am more familiar with linux to which I use the following

```
cat wo.txt2 | grep "WORK\|pdf|" | sed 's/^.*WORK/WORK/' >> wo.txt
```

There is about 17k lines in my text file

Comment: Use a text editor and replace `C:\Users\My Computer\SkyDrive\` with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayeExpansion
set "input=wo.txt2"
set "output=wo.txt"
>"%output%" (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "%input%"') do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
    if defined ln set "ln=!ln:*WORK=WORK!"
    (echo(!ln!)
    endlocal
  )
)
```

Note that the search for WORK is case insensitive.

The FINDSTR is used to prefix each line with the line number followed by colon, so as to preserve blank lines.

Delayed expansion is toggled on and off within the loop so as to preserve any `!` that may exist in the source file.

A much simpler solution is to use my [JREPL.BAT regex text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a pure script based utility (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

From the command line:

```
jrepl "^.*WORK" "WORK" /f "wo.txt2" /o "wo.txt"
```

You must use CALL JREPL if you use the command within a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

Use notepad++, open file, press alt key and select the "columns" of text you don't want with mouse. While you pressing alt key you stay in column mode. Release alt key and press del. This is valid if all lines have same number of chars to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at string functions like this example :

```
   set str=teh cat in teh hat  
   echo.%str%
   set str=%str:teh=the% 
   echo.%str%
```

You basically want to replace `C:\Users\My Computer\SkyDrive\` with a blank.

Here are a list of string functions you can use: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.MidString

Comment: No, the OP wants to replace everything from the beginning of the line, up until the first occurrence of WORLD with WORLD.